# replacing the part of the file path in postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a column called path containing 1000 rows of the file's path, such as :

\home\me\Desktop\analysis\rep139\android-arabic-reader\AndroidManifest.xml

.
.
I want to replace the first six parts of this file's path "\home\me\Desktop\analysis\rep139\android-arabic-reader" with a different one and keep the remaining.
I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: What have you tried/researched so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the replacement be the same for all paths, say `\a\b\c\d\e\f\`, you may use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` here:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET path = REGEXP_REPLACE(path, '\\.*?\\.*?\\.*?\\.*?\\.*?\\.*?\\', '\a\b\c\d\e\f\');
```